# Spring Batch retry doesn't work in Java if the app implements the CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, spring-batch, spring-retry

Taking as reference [Retry not working with Spring Batch with Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170179/retry-not-working-with-spring-batch-with-java-config) I checked in the code of the following spring batch reader retry example https://github.com/atulkulkarni18/spring-batch-reader-retry and the retry functionality works as expected.
However implementing the CommandLineRunner (as showed in the below code), the retry functionality doesn't work... can anybody advise?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableRetry
public class Stack56170179Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Stack56170179Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("myJob").start(step1()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return steps.get("step1").<String, String>chunk(1).reader(myReader())
                .processor(myProcessor())
                .writer(myWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job(), params);
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MyReader myReader() {
        return new MyReader();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MyProcessor myProcessor() {
        return new MyProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MyWriter myWriter() {
        return new MyWriter();
    }

}

public class MyReader implements ItemReader<String> {

    private long count;
    private long retryCount;

    @Override
    @Retryable(include = { MyException.class }, maxAttempts = 5)
    public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        final long value = count;
        System.out.println("MyReader : " + value);

        if (value == 3 && retryCount <= 2) {
            retryCount++;
            System.out.println("****");
            Thread.sleep(500);
            throw new MyException();
        }

        if (value < 5) {
            count++;
            Thread.sleep(500);
            return String.valueOf(value);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}


public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String process(final String arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MyProcessor : " + arg0);
        return arg0;
    }

}


public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {

    @Override
    public void write(final List<? extends String> arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MyWriter : " + arg0);
    }

}

public class MyException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Expected output:

```
MyReader : 0
MyProcessor : 0
MyWriter : [0]
MyReader : 1
MyProcessor : 1
MyWriter : [1]
MyReader : 2
MyProcessor : 2
MyWriter : [2]
MyReader : 3
****
MyReader : 3
****
MyReader : 3
****
MyReader : 3
MyProcessor : 3
MyWriter : [3]
MyReader : 4
MyProcessor : 4
MyWriter : [4]
MyReader : 5
```

Comment: From the code you shared, what are you expecting to be retried?

Comment: Sorry, I added the missing classes and following is the expected output: MyReader : 0
MyProcessor : 0
MyWriter : [0]
MyReader : 1
MyProcessor : 1
MyWriter : [1]
MyReader : 2
MyProcessor : 2
MyWriter : [2]
MyReader : 3
****
MyReader : 3
****
MyReader : 3
****
MyReader : 3
MyProcessor : 3
MyWriter : [3]
MyReader : 4
MyProcessor : 4
MyWriter : [4]
MyReader : 5

Comment: Put the expected output into the question.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `CommandLineRunner` but with the `MyReader` object. You have created plain object and it is not Spring managed. 
Try creating spring managed bean like

```
 @Bean
 @StepScope
 public MyReader myReader() {
    return new MyReader();
 }
```

and use `myReader()` inside method `step1()` instead of `new MyReader()`.

Hope this help!

Comment: Hi Neetesh, I applied the change you commented (refer to the original post) but it didn't work. Btw, I added to the application.properties file spring.batch.job.enabled=false so the that batch is not executed at the app startup but executed through the run(String... args) method. Doing that the execution is thrown and retry is not executed.

Comment: I have added the code to github with the output. Please check https://github.com/neeteshbhardwaj/batch-retry-command-line-runner

Comment: Please check your pom and java version. FYI, I am using java8.

Comment: Neetesh, thank you so much for your example, it works awesome; my mistake, after I checked deeply my project I realized I didn't have the @EnableRetry annotation.

Comment: Btw, my final goal is to use JdbcCursorItemReader in my Reader and I was able to do it. For practicality, I created an example with FlatFileItemReader and it works very well https://github.com/jeronimogalicia/batch-retry-flatfile-item-reader